# R: aggregating list of time series by period

Tags: r, time-series

what would be the best way to aggregate several time series together by reference period? Ideally by using ts objects only.

For example, I have two monthly series TS1 and TS2, I want to get TSTOT:

```
TIME_PERIOD   TS1    TS2     TSTOT
2000-01-01     25     25       50
2000-02-01     35     30       65
2000-03-01     40     30       70
```

I have several ts objects so I could imagin some function working with a list.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a `merge` method.  You can do `transform(merge(ts1, ts2), TSTOT = TS1 + TS2)`

Answer (score 0):

If these are `ts` objects, we can use `merge`

```
ts1 <- ts(c(25, 35, 40), start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)
ts2 <- ts(c(25, 30, 30), start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12)
transform(merge(ts1, ts2, by = "row.names"), TSTOT = x.x + x.y)
```